# Algorithm for minimum number of arrows required to pop lined-up balloons

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve the problem Baloni on Kattis in Python, which can be found [here](https://open.kattis.com/problems/baloni). The problem requires to find the minimum amount of arrows that can pop a row of balloons of fixed varying heights. The arrow travels from the left to the right, popping all balloons that are in it's horizontal path. When it pops a balloon, the arrow 's height decreases by one. So a sequence of balloons with altitudes of [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] could be popped all at once because you could start the arrow at altitude 5 and it would slowly descend with each popped balloon. The question is, what is the minimum amount of arrows it would take to pop all the balloons?

Here is my current solution:

```
def calculate(balloons):
    balloons.sort(reverse=True)

    arrows = 0

    for i in range(len(balloons)):
        arrow_height = balloons[i]
        arrows += 1

        for j in range(i + 1, len(balloons)):
            balloons[j] = min(balloons[j], arrow_height - 1)

    return arrows
```

I have tried one test case and it already doesn't work. The test case is [2, 1, 5, 4, 3]. It should return 2, since you can start with a balloon at 2 which pops 2 and 1, and then another balloon at 5 which pops the remaining ones. Instead, it returns 5. I have no idea how to implement such an algorithm and my current one is just a rough estimate off the top of my head. How can I make a better algorithm?

Comment: The question states that the balloons have a minimum height of 1, so shooting it at height zero would do nothing. If it reaches zero the arrow can basically do nothing more.

Comment: The order of balloons is crucial, so sorting them will make your algorithm fail! I'd maintain a dictionary of {height: list of arrows} to easily parse balloons in linear time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop will increase `arrows` in every iteration, so `arrows` will always be equal to `len(balloons)`. All the other stuff you do with `balloons` is really irrelevant with regards to the value that `arrows` will get. So this cannot be right. There should be some condition that determines whether you need a new arrow or not.

Secondly, by sorting the input list you lose information. It would mean that both `1 2 3 4 5` and `5 4 3 2 1` would give the same result, yet from the examples it is clear that the results should be different for these two inputs.

It also is problematic that you overwrite `balloon[j]`. If for instance you have input `2 1 5 4 3`, you will destroy the value 5 in the first iteration of the loop (and several other values). There should be no reason to *change* the input list.

#### Approach

The idea is to check in each iteration whether you can match the balloon's height with a previous balloon that is one unit higher. At the same time keep track of how many balloons you have for each height you encounter. If there is a match with a previous balloon that is one unit higher, then remove that higher balloon. In all cases increment the counter for the current height, so to account for the current balloon.

At the end, count the number of balloons that are still there.

Here is an implementation:

```
def calculate(balloons):
    d = { height: 0 for height in balloons }
    for height in balloons:
        if d.get(height + 1, 0):
            d[height + 1] -= 1
        d[height] += 1
    
    return sum(d.values())

# main code
n = int(input())
balloons = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(calculate(balloons))
```

This passes all Katti tests.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, one of the arrows must be used to take out the highest balloon, and that arrow will not hit any balloons to its left. It may also take out some balloons to the right of the highest balloon as it falls back to earth.

Should there be more than one balloon at the greatest height, all must be taken out by separate arrows, in left-to-right order.

Next consider which of the remaining balloons is highest. By the same reasoning, one arrow must be used to target that balloon, and so on until all the balloons have been shot down.

We therefore can shoot down the highest balloon and reduce to zero the heights of that balloon and all balloons to its right that the arrow hits on its descent. This is then repeated until all balloons are at height zero. The number of arrows used is clearly the minimum number of arrows required to pop all the balloons.

---

Below is code to implement this in Ruby. With the explanation I will provide this can be viewed as pseudo-code which I expect can be converted to Python easily.

```
def pop_em_all(balloon_heights)
  heights = balloon_heights.dup
  shots = []
  loop do
    highest_left = highest_balloon_left(heights)
    break if heights[highest_left] == 0
    shots.push(highest_left)
    pop_with_shot(heights, highest_left)
  end
  shots
end
```

```
def highest_balloon_left(heights)
  heights.each_index.max_by { |i| heights[i] }
end
```

```
def pop_with_shot(heights, highest_left)
  current_height = heights[highest_left]
  (highest_left..(heights.size - 1)).each do |balloon|
    if heights[balloon] == current_height
      heights[balloon] = 0
      current_height -= 1
    end
  end
end
```

---

Let's try it.

```
pop_em_all [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  #=> [0]
pop_em_all [2, 1, 5, 4, 3]
  #=> [2, 0]
pop_em_all [2, 1, 5, 5, 4]
  #=> [2, 3, 0]
pop_em_all [2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 6, 1, 7, 3]
  #=> [7, 5, 2, 8, 0, 6]
```

---

The main method, `pop_em_all` initially creates a copy of `balloon_heights`, called `heights`. This is done to avoided mutating `balloon_heights` as `heights` is modified during the course of the calculations.

---

**Method `highest_balloon_left`**

method merely determines which of the remaining balloons is highest, where balloons are identified by their index into the array `heights`. If, for example,

```
heights = [2, 1, 5, 4, 3]
```

then

```
highest_balloon_left(heights)
  #=> 2
```

As will be seen, this modifies `heights` to:

```
heights = [2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

at which point

```
highest_balloon_left(heights)
  #=> 0
```

resulting in `heights` becoming `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, after which

```
highest_balloon_left(heights)
  #=> 0
```

signifies we are finished.

Should `heights = [2, 1, 5, 5, 3]`,

```
highest_balloon_left(heights)
  #=> 2
```

after which we will find

```
heights = [2, 1, 0, 5, 3]
```

and determine

```
highest_balloon_left(heights)
  #=> 3
```

---

**Method `pop_with_shot`**

Given the balloon that is targeted (index of `heights`), this method sets `heights[i]` to zero every balloon `i` that is shot down when balloon `highest_left` is targeted.

If `heights = [2, 1, 5, 4, 3]` and `hightest_left = 2` this will change `heights` to

```
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

`(highest_left..(heights.size - 1))` denotes a range from the index `highest_left` to the index of the last element of `heights`.

---

**Main method `pop_em_all`**

The variable `shots` holds an array, initially empty, that will hold the balloon targeted by each arrow shot (the indices of `heights` and `balloon_heights`). Upon the termination of the method the end the size of this array will equal the minimum number of arrows required to shoot down all the balloons.

At each step the highest balloon `i` is identified and targeted, `i` is appended to `shots` and `heights[j]` is set to zero for every balloon `j` that is shot down by that arrow. The procedure is repeated until `height[i]` equals zero for all balloons `i`, at which point we are finished, with `shots` containing the targeted balloons, in order, with the size of that array equal to the minimum number of arrows required to dispatch all the balloons.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that involves maintaining a dictionary of {height: list of arrows at this height}; it could probably be optimized, but it works:

```
def calculate(balloons):
    new_arrow = 0
    heights = {}
    for height in balloons:
        if not (arrows_list := heights.get(height)):
            # There's no arrow traveling at this height, we need to shoot a new one
            new_arrow += 1
            height -= 1
            if height:
                # If the arrow that popped the last balloon is still above ground, log it at the new height
                heights.setdefault(height, []).append(new_arrow)
        else:
            # No need for a new arrow, we'll just decrease the height of one
            arrow = arrows_list.pop()
            height -= 1
            if height:
                heights.setdefault(height, []).append(arrow)
    return new_arrow
                
                
print(calculate([2, 1, 5, 4, 3]))           # 2
print(calculate([4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2]))     # 2
print(calculate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))        # 6
```

Also, for completeness sake, here's a Python implementation of Cary Swoveland's solution:

```
def highest_balloon_left(heights):
    return heights.index(max(heights))


def pop_with_shot(heights, highest_left):
    current_height = heights[highest_left]
    for balloon in range(highest_left, len(heights)):
        if heights[balloon] == current_height:
            heights[balloon] = 0
            current_height -= 1
    return heights


def pop_em_all(balloon_heights):
    heights = balloon_heights.copy()
    shots = []
    while True:
        highest_left = highest_balloon_left(heights)
        if heights[highest_left] == 0:
            break
        shots.append(highest_left)
        pop_with_shot(heights, highest_left)
    return shots


print(pop_em_all([2, 1, 5, 4, 3]))          # [2, 0]
print(pop_em_all([4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2]))    # [2, 0]
print(pop_em_all([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))       # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```